# Dayjs timezone change time value, how to keep in local?

Tags: node.js, typescript, date, timezone, dayjs

I noticed `dayjs/plugin/timezone` making unexpected results. (maybe lack of my understanding)

```
// tz time is +UTC09:00, dayjs.tz.setDefault(korea);
// my nodejs time is +UTC00:00

const time = 1678806000000;

dayjs.tz(time).toDate());
  // return date object 
 "2023-03-14T06:00:00.000Z" // 167877360000
```

I was surprised by this result because I thought that converting to a different timezone would only change the timezone offset and not the actual time value.

I have two questions:
Here is two question.

1. Why is dayjs.tz designed to work this way? Is it a bug or intentional? I thought that changing the timezone should only affect how the time is displayed, not the actual value of the timestamp.
2. How can I prevent dayjs.tz from changing the actual time value when converting to a different timezone? I've heard of the "keepLocalTime" option, but it doesn't seem to exist in the TypeScript declaration for dayjs.tz.

I heard about "keepLocalTime" option
But according to type declaration(of typescript) it dose not exists on dayjs.tz

```
dayjs.tz(time,timezone,?)
```

Only exists in dayjs().tz(timezone, true);

*Maybe I should use `dayjs().tz(timezone,true)` instead `dayjs.tz()`
I may have to use  But it seems to be quite cumbersome to always put the timezone in the first argument of `dayjs().tz()`

---

This was turn out `dayjs < 1.10.4 bug`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original assumption was correct - The timestamp value should not change, regardless of what time zone you provide.  Unix timestamps are always in terms of UTC.

Seems to be working fine here:

```js
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_utc)
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_timezone);
dayjs.tz.setDefault('Asia/Seoul');

const time1 = 1678806000000;
const time2 = dayjs.tz(time1).toDate().getTime();

console.log(time1);
console.log(time2);
console.log('equal:', time1 === time2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.7/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.7/plugin/utc.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.7/plugin/timezone.min.js"></script>
```

Perhaps you have an older version with a bug that's since been fixed?

Comment: I figure out it was dayjs < 1.10.4 bug! Thank you!